# Copy a line to a text file incrementing a number within the line

Tags: file, text, copy, line, increment

I have a line which I need to copy to a text file 250 times incrementing a number within the line.
The line is this:

```
https://xxxxx-1.b.xxxxx.com/xxx/djset/xxxxx-0001.mp4
```

I need the number 0001 to be incremented by 1 in each consecutive line so that I would get a file with lines like this:

```
https://xxxxx-1.b.xxxxx.com/xxx/djset/xxxxx-0001.mp4
https://xxxxx-1.b.xxxxx.com/xxx/djset/xxxxx-0002.mp4
https://xxxxx-1.b.xxxxx.com/xxx/djset/xxxxx-0003.mp4
https://xxxxx-1.b.xxxxx.com/xxx/djset/xxxxx-0004.mp4
```

Thank you.

Comment: Hi kalehrl, did you have a question? Make sure to include the code you have and your approach so someone can help you. Where are you getting stuck? You're unlikely to be given a working program without putting in some work yourself.

Comment: I can add a line to a file with echo command:
echo "https://xxxxx-1.b.xxxxx.com/xxx/djset/xxxxx-0001.mp4" >> file.txt
But I need a command which will add 250 of these lines and increment the number in them.

Comment: It sounds like you need a loop. If you add the programming language to the question (and add it as a tag as well) and add the code you have so far, then people will be more likely to find the question. Use the edit button. It sounds like you're writing a bat file? If so, add batch-file to the tags. Something you might find helpful is using the 'help' command in command prompt (cmd)

Comment: No need because this site did it for me without the need for programming language:
http://www.mynikko.com/tools/tool_incrementstr.html

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question and accept it as an answer then!

Answer (score 0):

This site did it for me: mynikko.com/tools/tool_incrementstr.html